# trigger click event based on count of JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, triggers

I have a `b-dropdown` in my parent.vue where I select an `item` and send Props (e.g. 1111, 2222, ...  and so on) to my child.vue.

Now I need to check e.g. if my props-value is `1111` how many `rows` (my definition of rows in this case are 0 and 1 so **two rows**) are in this JSON-Object and than trigger my `click-event` based on this count to add the amount of elements to my template.

My question is if this is possible and if yes how to do that?

Thank You!

in my template of child.vue:

```
<div class="mt-2">
  <b-button @click="addElement" variant="block">Add element</b-button>
</div>
```

my script:

```
import json from './json/json.json'

data() {
  return {
    inputs: [{}]
    json: json,
  }
}

methods: {
  addElement() {
    this.inputs.push({});
  },
}

props: ["item"]
```

my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "1111": {
            "0": {
                "Number": 1234
            },
            "1": {
                "Number": 4321
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "2222": {
            "0": {
                "Number": 6789
            },
            "1": {
                "Number": 9876
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get object size by `Object.keys({"0": {"Number": 1234}, "1": "x"}).length`.

Applied to your code:

```
addElement() {
   if(this.item === '1111'){
     for(let key in this.json[0]['1111'])
         this.inputs.push({});
     }
     //or
     this.addSomething(Object.keys( this.json[0]['1111'] ).length)

   }    
},
```

Comment: but now I'm pushing my element only one time.. I need to push it on count of lenght..

Comment: updated example, to push a count of length {}